# Can't encode slash in URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, urlencode

`http://myhost/MyController/DoSomething/Anything%252fAnything` is a bad request

`http://myhost/MyController/DoSomething/Anything%2fAnything` is the same as  `http://myhost/MyController/DoSomething/Anything/Anything`

What URL sends the string `"Anything/Anything"` to my controller?

How to make `Html.ActionLink` to generate that URL?

**EDIT:** It should be able to handle `"Anything/Anything/Anything/Anything....../Anything"` also

I'm using MVC 3.

Comment: How are you calling http://myhost/MyController/DoSomething/Anything%252fAnything ?

Comment: I'm calling myhost/MyController/DoSomething/Anything/Anything but it makes the routing system to get lost so I tried to encode slashes with %252f and %2f but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, but HOW are you calling it? Is it through some helper in your view? If so, can you post the code?

Comment: Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define a route that defines variable lenght routes, you can use this kind of definition:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Put it before others route definitions in your `global.asax.cs`

Answer (score 0):

The routing machinery wants to handle the slashes.
So add a routing rule such as

```
url = [controller]/[action]/[id1]/[id2]
```

See [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Or use urls such as

```
http://myhost/MyController/DoSomething/Anything?id2=Anything
```

It may be possible to handle as a default--but in that case, the rules for the other routes will have to explicitly NOT match your controller/action name. Otherwise a prior rule will apply.

**It could also be** that the entire url is available from a system var. Is your controller being called at all?

Comment: Hi Larry. My controller is not being called. My actual route is something like "Announce-Job-For-{seo_friendly_category_name}/{category_id}". ActionLink is able to generate links even when seo_friendly_category_name contains slashes but controller is not called at all. So I'm trying to encode the slashes.

Comment: Your controller is not being called because none of the routes matches the incoming url. The outgoing link creation is separate. Add a matching route for your url and your controller will then be called. Remember that the order of the route definitions count.

Comment: It matches. If not then ActionLink wouldn't generate the seo friendly link.